# compile two js files using closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have two js files:

1.js

```
(function(){
  function setLength(a,len){
  a.length=len;
}
  ...........
})();
```

2.js:

```
function View(){
  setLength(this,3);
}
```

Note,the `2.js` will access the method (`setLength`) defined in `1.js`.

So I want the compiler compile these two files using the same replacement.

I want this kind of result:

```
(function(){
  function x(a,b){
  a.length=b;
}
  ...........
})();

function View(){
  x(this,3);
}
```

Is this possible?

BTW,I use the compiler.js to compile the files:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js file.js --js_output_file file.min.js
```

This is the single file,I want to compile more than one file and each have its own output file,something like this:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js file.js,file2.js --js_output_file file.min.js,file2.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile these two files using the same replacement, two options of closure compiler can help

```
 
 --variable_map_input_file VAL          : File containing the serialized version
                                           of the variable renaming map produced
                                           by a previous compilation
 --variable_map_output_file VAL         : File where the serialized version of t
                                          he variable renaming map produced shou
                                          ld be saved
```

So you can

- First Compile 1.js and generate variable_map.

  ```
    java -jar compiler.jar --js 1.js --js_output_file 1.min.js -variable_map_output_file variable_map.txt
  ```
- Second Compile 2.js with the generated variable_map.

  ```
    java -jar compiler.jar --js 2.js --js_output_file 2.min.js --variable_map_input_file variable_map.txt
  ```

If 2.js will reference functions defined in 1.js, then the complier will need an [extern.js](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs) in order to compile 2.js

And with the output wrapper `(function(){%s})()`, all functions defined in 1.js can not be accessed from 2.js. You might need drop the wrapper, or use [export](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export)

Comment: It seems that use the `module` can meet my requirement.